# I need to select a group total as well as the individual rows?

Tags: mysql

I have the following result set...

```
Name | Team | Score
A    | 1    | 10
B    | 1    | 11
C    | 2    |  9
D    | 2    | 15
```

and I want to add an extra column to the results set for the team score so I can sort on it and end up with the following data set...

```
Name | Team | Score | TeamScore
D    | 2    | 15    | 24
C    | 2    |  9    | 24
B    | 1    | 11    | 21
A    | 1    | 10    | 21
```

So I end up with the top team first with the members in order.

My actual data is way more complicated than this and pulls in data from several tables but if you can solve this one I can solve my bigger issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table to a query that returns the total for each team:

```
select t.*, s.teamscore 
from tablename t 
inner join (
  select team, sum(score) teamscore
  from tablename
  group by team
) s on s.team = t.team 
order by s.teamscore desc, t.team, t.score desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wcyegSWNCowbdQwrXuE1Mn/0).
Results:

```
| Name | Team | Score | teamscore |
| ---- | ---- | ----- | --------- |
| D    | 2    | 15    | 24        |
| C    | 2    | 9     | 24        |
| B    | 1    | 11    | 21        |
| A    | 1    | 10    | 21        |
```

Comment: I should have spotted this one, this is what happens when you're working on a problem at midnight. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, we can simplify and just use `SUM` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Team,
    Score,
    SUM(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY Team) AS TeamScore
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    TeamScore DESC,
    Score;
```

Comment: I wanted to use a solution like this but unfortunately the server this is on is MySQL 5 so this isn't available to me. :-(

Comment: Sure, I half-expected that.  Moving forward, though, my answer is probably what most MySQL would want to/should be using.